# make behaviour when pattern does not contain recipe is non-obvious

Tags: makefile

When I call make all on the following I get the error message:

No rule to make target `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/node_degree_tracker.so

I can't see why is so. I expect the target `$(DST_DIR)/%.so` to match all the .so files in DST_DIR and copy them from SRC_DIR. Why isn't this happening?

```
SRC_DIR := ./src/spg
DST_DIR := ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth
SRC_FILES := node_degree_tracker spatialgrowth splay data_structures
DST_FILES_CYTHON = $(patsubst %,$(DST_DIR)/%.so,$(SRC_FILES))

$(DST_DIR): 
    virtualenv --system-site-packages venv
    mkdir $(DST_DIR)

$(DST_DIR)/%.py: $(SRC_DIR)/%.py $(DST_DIR)
    cp $< $@

compile:
    cd ./src/spg && \
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace

.PHONY: $(SRC_DIR)/%.so
$(SRC_DIR)/%.so: compile

$(DST_DIR)/%.so: $(SRC_DIR)/%.so $(DST_DIR)
    cp $< $@

all: $(DST_FILES_CYTHON)
    cp $(SRC_DIR)/simulate_spg.py $(DST_DIR)/.
```

make -d as per Etan's request:

```
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
  Considering target file `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/node_degree_tracker.so'.
   File `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/node_degree_tracker.so' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `src/spg/node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/node_degree_tracker.so,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/RCS/node_degree_tracker.so,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/RCS/node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/s.node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/SCCS/s.node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `src/spg/node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `src/spg/node_degree_tracker.so'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker.so'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `src/spg/node_degree_tracker.so,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker.so'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `src/spg/RCS/node_degree_tracker.so,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker.so'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `src/spg/RCS/node_degree_tracker.so'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker.so'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `src/spg/s.node_degree_tracker.so'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `node_degree_tracker.so'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `src/spg/SCCS/s.node_degree_tracker.so'.
   No implicit rule found for `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/node_degree_tracker.so'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/node_degree_tracker.so'.
  Must remake target `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/node_degree_tracker.so'.
make: *** No rule to make target `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/planar_growth/node_degree_tracker.so', needed by `all'. Stop.
```

Comment: Include the output from `make -d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$(SRC_DIR)/%.so: compile
```

This is a pattern rule without a recipe. I can't find the reference at the moment, but this is a problem, at least in certain versions of Make.

So give it a recipe that does nothing, like this:

```
$(SRC_DIR)/%.so: compile
    @:
```

or this:

```
$(SRC_DIR)/%.so: compile;
```

Comment: A pattern rule without a recipe isn't a problem, per se: it's just that its documented behavior is somewhat unexpected; a pattern rule without a recipe _deletes the pattern rule_.  This is true in all versions of GNU make, since pattern rules were added.

Comment: @MadScientist: I could vaguely remember that, but couldn't find it in the manual; you should answer, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @MadScientist I'll leave this for 24 hours in case you want to give a canonical answer. If not I'll accept Beta's answer.

Comment: Also, I have a version of this makefile than ran on cygwin around a year ago. This had a pattern rule with no recipe and worked as I expected.

Comment: @Beta you stated the problem and solution: you should get the accept.  I just clarified one thing (feel free to update your answer with the clarification).  Cheers!